# Is using custom attributes valid?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to cancel any links and add extra attributes to each one. Below is how I've achieved this.

```
function anularEnlaces(){
    $('nav a').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).attr('href','javascript:void(0)');
        $(this).attr('hrefnot',href);
        $(this).attr('nivel','uno');
        $(this).attr('seccion','dos');
    });
}
```

My question is, is that a valid/recommended way to add custom atributes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not like that. If you are using the HTML5 doctype you can use the new [`data-*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) attributes, and then use the jQuery [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method:

```
$(this).data("hrefnot", href);
```

And HTML:

```
<a href="somewhere.html" data-hrefnot="something">A link</a>
```

If you don't need to store data on your tags initially, then it doesn't matter whether you use the HTML5 doctype or not (jQuery's `data` method will still work).

Comment: but if i do this i can't see the current values in firebut. is that normal?

Comment: Yes, that's normal. jQuery stores `data` internally (so that you still have valid markup if you're not using an HTML5 doctype).

Answer (score 3):

Valid if you are using HTML5, you can add your own custom data attributes `data-`:

[HTML5 Custom Data Attributes (data-*)](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

and you can use jQuery's [`$.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to read and modify them.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should use [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead for custom element attributes, and [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) ( or better yet [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) ) for standard html attributes .

---

Example of data() usage :

```
<a hred="some/url" data-custom="value">test</a>

// getter
var customValue = $('a').data('custom');
var customUndefined = $('a').data('testing');
```

Now customValue contains "value" string, and customUndefined contains undefined

```
// setter
$('a').data('custom', 'test');
$('a').data('testing', true);
```