# is it standard to use undefinded attribute in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I sometime use undefined attribute.

---

**Example**

```
<ul>
  <li id="goFirst" url="abcd.jsp">menu1</li>
  <li id="goSecond" url="abcd2.jsp">menu2</li>
</ul>
```

---

By using attribute("**url**"), I could easily access attribute by jQuery.

**Usage in jQuery**

```
var url = $("#goFirst").attr(url);
location.href="url";
```

However, I'm not sure whether this is right way to use or non-standard way.

Sorry for my English. thanks

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225918/is-using-custom-attributes-valid and I suppose other questions as well.

Comment: Sorry, I tried searching with my humble English skill but failed...T_T

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `data-url` instead, this is [valid HTML](http://caniuse.com/#search=datase).

```
<li id="goFirst" data-url="abcd.jsp">
```

Then you can use:

```
var url = $("#goFirst").attr("data-url");
```

Or:

```
var url = $("#goFirst").data("url");
```

Comment: `data-*` attributes [can be used even if it isn't HTML5](http://caniuse.com/#search=datase)