# Move element between containers with same order using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have two panels, one on the left and another one on the right side. There are many spans in the left panel. When user clicks on any span in the left panel, I move them to right panel using the following code:

```
$(".left-panel span").click(function(){
    $(".right-panel").append(this);
});
```

Everything is OK, just If user clicks on the 5th span first, then clicks on 2nd span, I want the 2nd span to be before 5th span.

I want the spans to move with same other in the left panel.

**Note:** Please do not suggest to use `jQuery.prepend()` function. Think about other spans too.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129259/re-arranging-sorting-divs-without-re-inserting-into-dom) could be helpful in terms of inserting spans into `right-panel` and then reordering them based on some condition

Comment: are there any on the right to begin with?

Comment: @Freak_Droid So insert before what?

Comment: @andrew assume that there is 5th span on the right side and now we want insert the 2nd one.

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev Nice! that did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First store a `data` variable with each span to indicate it's original position. Then use `.sort()` to sort the spans based on the index:

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/saS5R/)

```
$(".left-panel span").each(function(){
   $(this).data('sort', $(this).index()); 
});

$(".left-panel span").click(function(){
    $(".right-panel").append(this);

    $('.right-panel span').sort(function(a, b){
        return $(a).data('sort') > $(b).data('sort');
    }).appendTo($('.right-panel'));
});
```

---

As [KevinB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b) points out in the comments. jQuery's `.sort()` is not documented and so if you prefer you can use the native Javascript [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

- [KevinB's example](http://jsfiddle.net/saS5R/1/)
- [My example](http://jsfiddle.net/4mHHZ/)

Comment: it might not be as pretty, but i'd suggest using `Array.prototype.sort` instead, just in case `$.fn.sort` is removed one day (it isn't documented.) http://jsfiddle.net/saS5R/2/

Comment: Good point, added your demo to the answer (hope you don't mind) :)

Answer (score -1):

i think you have to add a filed to the panel. or use other filed of their sequence

```
<span sort_id="1" ..../〉  ..
```

then you need loop all panel on right to get the max or min sort_id or the closest sort_id

at last you can use insertBefore() or insertAfter() to add this panel

Comment: This methods needs a lot of loops through DOM elements

Comment: Dont use arbitrary attributes, use data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225918/is-using-custom-attributes-valid

Comment: it just a example. we need know how to sort them or their original sequence. this will be less calculation